# Using a fragment as a ListView header in only one orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement an activity that supports the two orientations below:

```
+--------------------------+      +-------------+---------------------------+
|                          |      |             |                           |
|                          |      |             |                           |
|                          |      |             +--------           --------+
|   Header View            |      |             |                           |
|   (from fragment)        |      |             |                           |
|                          |      | Fragment    +--------           --------+
+--------------------------+      |             |                           |
|                          |      |             |          ListFragment     |
|                          |      |             |                           |
+---------         --------+      |             +--------           --------+
|         ListFragment     |      |             |                           |
|                          |      |             |                           |
+---------         --------+      +-------------+---------------------------+
|                          |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
```

This isn't hard if I use fragments defined in my layout XML everywhere. The challenge comes from the fact that I want the header fragment to scroll with the ListFragment in portrait orientation. To accomplish this, I'm inflating the XML myself and adding it as a header view. This works too, until I rotate the device (from portrait to landscape, the other way around works), at which point, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #3: Duplicate id 0x7f06002d, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.example.MyHeaderFragment
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:275)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
```

I think this is coming from the fact that I'm loading a fragment manually in one orientation and automatically from the layout in another. I can't think of a way around this.

One solution that I thought of was to define the portrait layout in XML without the header view (the header wouldn't scroll with the ListFragment) and then move the view from above the ListFragment into the header view as soon as the view is created, but this hasn't worked.

Is this design doomed to fail or does somebody have a clever solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved this by removing the `id`s from the fragments. The `FragmentManager` now no longer sees them as the same, so doesn't throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the header view from your list before orientation change.

Use `adapter.removeHeader(view)` in the appropriate place (`onStop` or `onDestroy`) and I think things will work as you wish.

Comment: I also tried this without success. The fragment was still around although the view had been removed.

Comment: Well bugger.  Glad to see you found a solution though.